# Applying function on particular rows with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How compute `mean()` or other function on particular rows using GroupBy. Consider the following dataframe:

```
 In[239]: df.groupby(['id'])['summary']
Out[239]: 
                summary
id         
11                  2.0
11                  3.0
11                  3.0
11                  3.0
11                  3.0
11                  3.0
14                  NaN
14                  NaN
14                  NaN
14                  NaN
14                  NaN
14                  2.0
17                  NaN
17                  NaN
17                  NaN
17                  NaN
17                  5.0
17                  5.0
18                  4.0
18                  5.0
18                  4.0
18                  3.0
18                  3.0
18                  4.0
23                  2.0
23                  1.0
23                  2.0
23                  1.0
23                  3.0
23                  1.0
                ...
81                 10.0
81                  9.0
81                  8.0
81                  8.0
81                  9.0
81                  9.0
82                  0.0
82                  0.0
82                  0.0
82                  0.0
82                  0.0
82                  0.0
83                  1.0
83                  0.0
83                  1.0
83                  2.0
83                  2.0
83                  1.0
84                  2.0
84                  0.0
84                  0.0
84                  0.0
84                  1.0
84                  NaN
85                  5.0
85                  4.0
85                  4.0
85                  5.0
85                  5.0
85                  4.0
```

1. How to compute `mean()` of ***only first three*** rows of each id?
2. How to compute `mean()` of ***masked*** (index with some conditions) rows within each id ?

For example:

```
df.groupby(['id'])['summary'].mean()
```

will compute mean() of each group (defined by id), but it takes all rows.

Comment: for the first 3 rows, iterate through the first 3 items in a list using a count.

Comment: @Artagel, can you show a code how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would get both the mean of the first three rows and the mean of some mask.

```
df.groupby('id')['summary'].agg([lambda x: x.iloc[:3].mean(), lambda x: x[mask].mean()])
```

Comment: I completely missed off lambda! Awesome!